# jquery absolute position animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm having trouble with a piece of code

```
$(function(){  
 $('input.no').click(function(){  
 $(this).animate({"left" : "80px"}, 150);  
 $(this).removeClass().addClass('click');   });  

 $('input.click').click(function(){  
 $(this).animate({"right" : "0px"}, 150);  
  });  
});
```

and here you can see the full code
http://pastebin.me/a5b13717c5d7125cd904572c041ce3e1
not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using live or delegate:

Add a class to the button like: slider-button

```
$(function() {
  $('.slider-button').bind('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('no')) {
       $(this).animate({"left" : "80px"}, 150);  
       $(this).removeClass('no').addClass('click');  
    } else {
       $(this).animate({"left" : "0px"}, 150);  
       $(this).removeClass('click').addClass('no');  
    }       
  });    
});
```

Comment: not working ? i mean i'm not sure i tryed it in pastebin and it works only for the left:80px part it doesn't come back

Comment: @andrei  I made a fix now try

Comment: @andrei  {"left" : "0px"} was needed

Comment: @andrei if you refresh pastebin you will see it working. Nice effect

Answer (score 0):

The reason the second click is not handled is that at the time you bind your handler, there are no `input.click` elements, so the handler isn't bound.

To make sure the handler is bound after you change the input's class, you need to use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$(function() {
  $('input.no').live('click', function() {
    $(this).animate({"left" : "80px"}, 150);  
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('click');  
  });

  $('input.click').live('click', function() {
    $(this).animate({"right" : "0px"}, 150);  
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('no');  
  });
});
```